# php script prevent direct access

Tags: php

I am using ajax to get value from php scripts (for example cost.php) and i know it would be easy to access it directly and get that value. I am even running cron job on same script(cost.php) so cron job would not work if i use following...

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
  //code here
  die('Invalid Request!');
}
```

Is this the safe way to prevent, and cron jobs would not work if i use the above code, so what can i use to secure value from end user. thanks.

Comment: Why would you hide the value from the end user? Use a password defined from your cronjob wich is defined in the php script too. And use no security other than sql attack protection for the ajax calls for the value.

Comment: If the script is returning a value to an Ajax request, the data is already 'out there' for the user to see.

Comment: we are generating value from this script, which we don't want to get scrapped.

Answer (score 4):

In order to separate execution of cronjob, you can consider to use [php_sapi_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php)

A simple usage (more reliable that depend on server side variables) :-

```
if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") // via cronjob or via cli
{
  die("invalid request");
}
```

PS: constant PHP_SAPI carry the same value, so you can rewrite to :-

```
if (PHP_SAPI == "cli")
{
  die("invalid request");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!eregi('cost.php',basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]))) { die('access denied'); }
```

Comment: @richsage: Yeah right, thanks for mentioning ... just copied the line from an old project. So, use preg_match instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a secret password for the cronjob

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['cronpw']) && $_REQUEST['cronpw'] == 'supersecret')
{
    // this is the cronjob
}
else
{
    // this not
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of code to stop direct script access.

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

If you want to allow AJAX requests then,

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH') &&
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest')
exit('You are not allowed here...');
```