# How to prevent a PHP page from being accessed directly?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, token

Below is a javascript snippet that I am using as part of a AJAX script.  How do I prevent user_back_end_friends.php from being accessed directly?  I don't want people to be able to go to domain.com/user_back_end_friends.php and see a list of friends.

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#user_friends").tokenInput("/user_back_end_friends.php", {
            theme: "sometheme", userid: "<?php echo $id; ?>"
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is what I found but not sure how to implement it with the javascript code above:

I use this in the page I need to call it in:

```
$included=1;include("user_back_end_friends.php");
```

When I have to prevent direct access I use:

```
if(!$included){ die("Error"); }
```

But how do I add this $included part of the script in my javascript code?

Comment: I don't see how the include trick is going to work since the jQuery call to `user_back_end_friends.php` is a fresh one and won't have any variables from the current environment in it. I don't know of a foolproof way of preventing someone from accessing `user_back_end_friends.php` directly except by checking the origin of the request - should be localhost in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php script prevent direct access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000537/php-script-prevent-direct-access)

Answer (score 11):

There is no point in protecting javascript code, you need to protect only the server-side code.

Anyway, I think your approach is not the right one; if you already have a logged-in user / a user ID, I would just use the user ID from the session instead of a user ID that is supplied by the javascript. That way there is no way anybody can tamper with it.

So you could start your page with:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'))
{
  // do stuff with the user ID
}
else
{
  // display error message?
}
```

Comment: Hey the script i have is showing user friends and their id's.  So somebody who is technical enough would look at the source code and perhaps might try domain.com/user_back_end_friends.php and see their friend's user_ids.  I know its not a big deal but wouldn't want anyone snooping around.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry if i am not seeing it as i am new to PHP.  Do you mean using this on the page that uses the javascript OR the user_back_end_friends.php page?

Comment: @ariel On the backend. Now you are sending a user ID from javascript to your php script. If you already have a logged-in user, you can skip that completely and just use the user ID that you already have server-side in the session. That way the user ID is no input for the php script, the script simply takes it from the logged in user and nobody can feed another value to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot completely block access to this script by the very nature of the web.

You can check for referrer information, input validation, you could create a session variable on the parent page that's checked on the child page.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following. Note that this is NOT the most secure, as other answers have mentioned, you can't completely block access to this script (link to an easy bypass is provided), but for my simple purposes this that worked very well -

```
define('_REFERURL',              'http://www.example.com');            // This is the full URL of your domain that will be calling your PHP script(s)
```

Then create a function that checks the referring URL (which should be from your domain)

```
function allow_user()
{
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == _REFERURL)
        {
                return true;
        }
        else
        {
                return false;
        }
}
```

Use:

```
if (allow_user())
{
     // Do things
}
else
{
     // Alert, direct access attempted
}
```

Easy by pass: http://www.datatrendsoftware.com/spoof.html