# GET ajax request implemetation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for way to load html via GET ajax request, thats working fine, but I want to load the html with in the page only if the main view is already loaded and the user logged in does not make any difference here. Even if the logged in user try to directly access the page, then the response need to be empty.

Example. If user type dummydomain.com/index.php then the desired page will be shown, after that ajax request to dummaydomain.com/fetchdata will send the desired data, but if some user type dummydomain.com/fetchdata directly he will no be shown anything.

Kindly guide me in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent a PHP page from being accessed directly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593249/how-to-prevent-a-php-page-from-being-accessed-directly)

Comment: thats not what I want! even if the logged in user try to access that dummaydomain.com/fetchdata, then the response need to be empty.

Comment: That is what the duplicate question is asking for too. The problem is that you are trying to give some information to the browser (which is totally under the control of the user) without giving that information to the user too. That's simply impossible.

Comment: Impossible!! really ??? isn't it any other way around! how soundcloud & quora are doing this then???

Comment: Probably with some trivially bypassed trick. I can't tell what it is because I have no idea what content on those two sites you are talking about.

Comment: any section that is loaded via ajax! as Likes & Who to follow section on soundcloud.com/stream page

Comment: They'd just requiring the Auth/Authz data in the headers `Authorization: OAuth redacted`. It took about 4 minutes to create an account, 1 minute to find the URL being requested, 5 seconds to see the content of the URL and 5 more seconds to bypass it, and about 30 seconds to figure out what it was about the request that was the key factor. As a technique to hide content from users, it is pointless. Soundcloud are doing it to make sure users only get to see their own private data, not to hide that data from users. Cookies are the usual way to do that, but they are playing across domains.