# How to prevent users from accessing files from URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-access

I use javascript to bring xml data or MySQL data and as you know I should use some ajax code to do this (call proxy php code) like following :

```
var url = 'include-xml/leagues.xml'; 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseNamesMidnight
    });
```

but my problem is that if somebody try to access the file from the URL directly . Is there anyway to prevent people from accessing the files that I use them as proxy?

Comment: No. Anything the browser can do with Javascript can be done manually by the user.

Comment: Just a comment: note that with Inspect Element, users can always access ajax traffic.

Comment: You could do some mitigation by [checking the `X-Requested-With` request header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000537/php-script-prevent-direct-access) and reject if not present; not worth the effort imho.

Comment: Of course, if this is a member service you should lock it down with session management.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Webservices are like anything else you can put on the web: When you don't want everyone in the world to access your data, don't put it on a public website.

You could have your webservice check the users [Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)-header and only serve requests which originate from your website. But this header is optional and provided by the user-agent, so it can be faked by illicit users or omitted by legitimate users, so it's not a reliable way.

You could also have your webservice use authentication with username and password. That would at least restrict access to registred users and allow you to control which data each user can access. But it doesn't prevent users with login credentials from accessing the webservice without your website.